# using matlab dll file in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio-2012, dll

I created a dll file using "mcc" command in matlab from a simple add function like this:

```
function c = MyAdd(a,b)
    c = a + b;
```

I entered this command:

```
mcc -t -L C -W lib:libMyAdd -T link:lib MyAdd.m libmmfile.mlib
```

it makes these files:

```
libMyAdd.lib
libMyAdd.c
libMyAdd.h
libMyAdd.dll
```

then i created an empty C++ project in VS and wrote this source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "libMyAdd.h"

int main()
{
    double k[4];
    mwArray out;
    out.GetData(k, 4);
    // initialize MCR and lib
    if (!mclInitializeApplication(NULL,0))  {
        std::cerr << "could not initialize the application" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    if(!libMyAddInitialize()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not initialize the library" << std::endl;
        _getch();
        return -1;
    }

    try {
        // create input
        double g[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
        double h[] = {5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0};
        mwArray in1(2, 2, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
        mwArray in2(2, 2, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
        in1.SetData(g, 4);
        in2.SetData(h, 4);

        // call function
        mwArray out;
        MyAdd(1, out, in1, in2);

        // show result
        std::cout << "in1 + in2 = " << std::endl;
        std::cout << out << std::endl;

        double k[4];
        out.GetData(k, 4);
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            std::cout << k[i] << " " << std::endl;
        }

    } catch (const mwException& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return -2;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Unexpected error thrown" << std::endl;
        return -3;
    } 

    // cleanup
    libMyAddTerminate();   
    mclTerminateApplication();

    return 0;
}
```

I also added this paths to my include and library directory in project properties->VC++ Directories as well as my additional library directories in linker->general

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\extern\include
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft
```

Also, I added followings to Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies:

```
mclmcrrt.lib
libeng.lib
libmx.lib
libmex.lib
libmat.lib
mclmcr.lib
libMyAdd.lib
```

And since my matlab version is R2015a(64-bit), i changed the active solution platform to x64 (it was Win32).

the compiler shows no error, but a get a first-chance exception when I compile it (a picture of that uploaded).

what did i do wrong?
any suggestion?[a picture of that uploaded]

[the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbuEl.jpg)

Comment: What is the error or exception?

Comment: the error is a first-chance exception of access violation reading memory. you can see the error by clicking on the "the error image" link up there which i uploaded.

Comment: is'nt there any solution plz?